# How to create a document without value to MongoDB in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, jsp, servlets

In a relational database generally, you can define a field first then store data accordingly. In my case, I want to do the same to MongoDB to create a `collection` and document (fields) without value to test it.

I created a collection and empty document with field name in my Service class, but not sure how to post it to the database.

Here is the `service class`

```
public class PlayCardService {

    MongoDatabase database = dBUtils.getMongoDB();

    public PlayCardService() {
    }

    public void create(PlayCardService gc) {


        // Create or get table
        MongoCollection<Document> tcTbl = database.getCollection("PlayCard_tbl");

        // create document (field)
        Document pcDoc = new Document("PlayCardNumber", null).append("SecurityCode", null).append("Type",
                Arrays.asList("bronze", "silver", "gold"));

        pcTbl.insertOne(tcDoc);
}
```

Here is the add play card servlet just to test if it can create a collection in MongDB mlab

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    // create new card
    PlayCard pc = new PlayCard ();

    request.setAttribute("pcNumber", null);
    
    pcService.create(tc);

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

}

Comment: Before doing it, you need to refer some tutorials. There are a lot of tutorial, you can google it

Comment: thanks. I using mlab but, also want to do it programmatically